# AlertDialog with custom view disappears behind Soft Keyboard after entering a long text

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I have a simple `AlertDialog` with this custom `View`:

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter a comment"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_bold"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bold_b" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_italic"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/italic_i" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_underlined"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/underlined_u"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/add_link"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_link"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Problem**

A long text causes the `AlertDialog` to hide behind Soft Keyboard.
[image]

And the *FormattingBar* (**B** *I* U Link) is also hidden and only visible with a short text.

The `AlertDialog` should always stay over the Soft Keyboard and if the text is too long, the `EditText` has to be scrollable, but the *FormattingBar* and the `AlertDialog` buttons should always be visible.

[image]

**How can I do this?**

I already tried stuff like

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

but nothing worked.

Using `maxLines` causes problems with different devices. The number of maxlines varies.

Comment: why don't you set  maxHeight or nooflines??

Comment: @Rashiq It causes problems on different devices. Maybe it works on a phone, but on a tablet, the dialog would be to small.

Comment: okay. did yu try inputtype as multilinetext??

Comment: @Rashiq Yes I did.

Comment: it will give a scroller to your edittext. Now set height of editext with minheight or maxheight as your requiremnt by fetching from dimens value, where you have to create dimen values for each screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)` to your **`AlertDialog`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

> Activity

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showAlertDialog(this)

    }

    private fun showAlertDialog(
            context: Context
    ) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)

        dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.aa)

        val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
        dialog.show()
    }

}
```

> dialog layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter a comment"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_bold"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_italic"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_underlined"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_link"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `inputType`

Remove that line and try this code instead

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter a comment"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:maxHeight="90dp"/>
```

**Update** :

```
edittext.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext));
edittext.setMaxLines(5);
edittext.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
edittext.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

By using this method you can get the keyboard dynamic height and you can set the edittext static height % based on the total height of the screen

```
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
     public void onGlobalLayout(){
           int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight()- root.getHeight();
           // IF height diff is more then 150, consider keyboard as visible.  
        }
  });
```

this only works when `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: A maxHeight causes problems, because on a tablet it's 90dp height too, but I want to make the Edittext scrollable, if there is not space for the AlertDialog anymore. My InputType **must** be textMultiLine.

Comment: MaxLines causes problems on different devices too. It's like max height.

Comment: and try to check out this example https://github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheight/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/siebeprojects/samples/keyboardheight/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. Get the height of the device by adding the following method to your activity class

   ```
   public int getHeight(){

      DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
      int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
      return height;
   }
   ```
2. Set the MaxHeight according to the device height so it won't cause any problem on bigger devices like tablets by adding this block of code to your onCreate() method.

   ```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText); //The EditText in the Layout
    editText.setMaxHeight(getHeight()/3); //
   ```

The XML is ok but don't forget to add the id to the editText